# Crystal Reports XI, disappearing field with zero balance

Tags: crystal-reports

I have crystal reports XI, I am new to crystal reports and am not tech savvy, so please consider that in your reply. There is a section that does not populate at all when the value is zero. The whole section disappears on the generated reports. I need the section to show and I need the zero value to show. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

do a right click on that section(where the section name is), go to `section expert` and on the common tab see if you have something under `Suppress(No drill-down) X-2` button(might be red). There should be a condition that is suppressing the section when the field takes 0 value. You can suppress that condition putting // in-front on it or just delete it. You may also check if `Suppress Blank Section` is checked, if so remove the check mark.